# How to loop inside containers to select value in selenium?

Tags: java, loops, selenium, automation, containers

I have a product page which has the sizes inside containers, i tried to list elements and get size by text but the list always returns zero, i tried the xpath of the parent and child and i get the same error, How can i list the sizes and select specific size ?

```
public void chooseSize(String size) {
    String selectedSize;
    List<WebElement> sizesList = actions.driver.findElements(By.xpath("SelectSizeLoactor"));
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i <= sizesList.size(); i++) {
            if (sizesList.get(i).getText().toLowerCase().contains(size.toLowerCase()));
            {
                selectedSize = sizesList.get(i).getText();
                sizesList.get(i).click();
                assertTrue(selectedSize.equals(size));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Assert.fail("Couldn't select size cause of " + e.getMessage());

    }
```

[image: Product page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a quick solution i used part of the xpath with text() and passed the value of that text later then added the last of the xpath and it worked!

```
String SelectSizeLoactor = "//button[text()='"

public void chooseSize(String size) {
    String selectedSize;
    WebElement sizeLocator = actions.driver.findElement(By.xpath(SelectSizeLoactor+size.toUpperCase()+"']"));
    try {
            if (sizeLocator.getText().toUpperCase().contains(size.toUpperCase()));
            {
                selectedSize = sizeLocator.getText();
                sizeLocator.click();
                assertTrue(selectedSize.equals(size));
            }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Assert.fail("Couldn't select size cause of " + e.getMessage());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the proper selector would be:

```
actions.driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".SizeSelection-option"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below options

```
List<WebElement> sizesList = actions.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//[@class='SelectSizeLoactor']"));
List<WebElement> sizesList = actions.driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".SelectSizeLoactor"));
```